# Why is calling a MessageBox from a Console Application unmanaged code?

Tags: c#, unmanaged

In [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke) Platform Invoke example a `MessageBox` is called from a Console Application as unmanaged code.

I am wondering why that is? Isn't this the same `MessageBox` contained in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace, which is managed, as far as I know?

So why in that example is the `MessageBox` method unmanaged code?

Comment: No, it is not the same. In NET this is a class with just a static method named Show, in that example they are referencing the function present in the User32.dll (a core windows OS system dll) and of course this is unmanaged code. It just happens to have the same name, but they are two different things

Comment: @Steve, but is the static method making the same call to unmanaged code behind the scenes or is that different, too?

Comment: Yes, in NET they are calling that method after a lot of checks. You can see the source of NET MessageBox.Show here https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/MessageBox.cs,7b52788b4a218cca

Comment: In addition to what Steve said, note that you can always call the managed `MessageBox.Show` method if you reference `System.Windows.Forms` in your console app.

Comment: It is just an example, meant to teach but not meant to be practical.  Practically you'd just use the managed method, after adding a reference to System.Windows.Forms in your project.